# How to listen to all ports (UDP and TCP) or make them all appear open (linux)

Tags: firewalls, ports

I got an external Debian server. The problem is that my university campus doesn't allow connections to go outside when the port is different than TCP port 22, 80, 443, or UDP port 123. I tested them manually. On my Debian server I would like to listen to all my UDP and TCP ports so I can clearly figure out which TCP and UDP ports my university let through their firewall. Nmap is wonderful on the client side to test that, but what should I do on the server side?

Comment: As this appears to represent an unauthorized attempt at circumventing the university's security, I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Dude. He's only trying to find out what ports are allowed, not changing his grades.

Comment: Epic reference, chris.

Comment: @Iszi - I can't resist noting that not allowing "... connections to go outside when the port is different than TCP port 22, 80, 443, or UDP port 123" is hardly a *security measure* of any effect :-) Or is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you run a sniffer on the server and make sure it listens only to traffic coming in from a certain IP or network? Then run a tool like ftester and you should be able to tell what ports are allowed.

Comment: He probably wants to know if he can establish a TCP connexion, not just the initial SYN packet, so he also need to `accept()` the TCP connexion.

Comment: solved: `tcpdump -nnq src host <campus-external-ip> and not port ssh` since the campus firewall is not so advanced, on all ports I discovered I was able to make a full TCP and/or UDP connection.

Answer (score 11):

A simple and passive solution would be to log all incoming connection attempts to syslog, run your scan, and when you get home look at the logs. With iptables, you can log connections like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state new -j LOG --log-prefix "New connection: "
```

That way, you don't need to run a service that answers all connetion attempts.

Comment: +1, less complexity than mine and suitable for temporary testing.

Comment: Addendum thought: Use in tandem with mine and you'll may discover firewall rulesets with differences between inbound and outbound rules (SYN is seen coming in by server, SYN ACK is not seen by client)

Comment: He probably wants to know if he can establish a TCP connexion, not just the initial SYN packet, so he also need to `accept()` the TCP connexion.

Comment: @JeffFerland / curiousguy that'd be interesting, although I wouldn't expect a firewall that wants to prevent outgoing connections, to allow the SYNs in the first place

Comment: @chris Possible example (the one that prompted my comment): blocking email to prevent spam might be done by preventing any outbound communication to port 25 except for the ISP's servers. SYNs are seen, SYN ACKs back are dropped. Also, accepting a connection with iptables won't matter if there isn't a back-end service for it.

Comment: My server sees the SYNs and on my computer nmap sees the SYN ACKs. Everything is good, solved with this cmd: `tcpdump -nnq src host <campus-external-ip> and not port ssh`

Comment: By the way the network admin let very few udp port "go out", among them are the 123 (ntp), irc ones, msn, the 4000 and that's all. Guess what is the 4000? Diablo II.

Comment: @Michael lol @ Diablo :-) IRC doesn't use UDP to my knowledge btw, must be some other protocol.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it worked well, but how do I disable it?

Answer (score 7):

Simplistic method:

Use your regular application to list on one port. Use `iptables` to forward all ports to the open port by means of the dnat module.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i interface -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination your.ip:port
iptables -A PREROUTING -i interface -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination your.ip:port
```

Comment: "localhost:xxx" would be valid?

Also, I already have plenty of rules in the prerouting table, if I write this one in first, the other ones will still work right?

Comment: @Michael: not `localhost`, that will use the loopback interface. Use `ifconfig` to determine your IP address and use that in Jeff's commands above in place of `your.ip`.

Comment: netcat (`nc`) is an easy way to listen on a port

Comment: @Michael: "If no IP address is specified then only the destination port will be modified." -- so just the port number will do it.

Comment: @bstpierre Who wants to spawn 131,070 nc instances?

Comment: @JeffFerland: Sorry that wasn't clear, I meant combined with your iptables trick -- listen with nc on `your.ip:port`.

Comment: Thank you both, I crashed named, etc... while trying to spawn 65535 instances of nc -l -p $i haha. Well I tried it the dumb way.

Comment: The suggested solution did not quite work for me, but something similar did: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i INTERFACE -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination YOURIP:PORT`

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already done the server side for you [PortQuiz.net](http://portquiz.net/).

You should then be able to do this either manually on a web-browser or use your NMAP or script something automatic in something like Python.